# Updating a SQLite database with AsyncTask effectively and efficiently

Tags: android, json, sqlite, listview, android-asynctask

A SQLite database has fields to store Latitude and Longitude values in a table. A mailing address is input from users in an Add activity.

In the `AsyncTask` that fetches the LatLng object for the input address, the database write operation is the last statement of its `doInBackground` method. However, contrary to expectation, the write is happening **BEFORE** the JSON parsing of the response, writing NULL values for the lat and long **initially**.

The `ListView` that front-ends the table shows null Lat and Long values, but the right values after a refresh. The focus rushes back from the Add activity before the JSON parsing and all, which is not the desired behaviour. The `ListView` must return only after the right LatLng are populated in the table, until which an indeterminate progress bar should keep showing. This **IS** all working fine, ***except*** that

- the progress bar appears and vanishes too fast
- The `ListView` is back with other components of its list items properly populated, except the LatLong values.

The question is, how can the database write be forced to wait till the JSON parsing is complete?

Hope this verbose explanation of the situation will suffice. Please mention if more elaboration or code is required.

Many thanks in advance!

Relevant pseudo-code for your kind investigation:

The AsyncTask extension:

```
    private class Geocode extends AsyncTask<String, Void, LatLng>
{
    @Override
    protected LatLng doInBackground(String...addressToGeocode) 
    {
        int DELAY = 9000;
        URL geoCodeURL;
        String jsonResponse = null;
        String geoCodeRequestURL = Contract.HTTPS_GOOGLE_GEOCODE_PRE_ADDRESS_URL 
                                   + Uri.encode(addressToGeocode[0]); 

        // Get JSON response 
        try 
        {
            geoCodeURL = new URL(geoCodeRequestURL);
            URLConnection geoCodeURLConnection = geoCodeURL.openConnection();
            BufferedReader responseReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (geoCodeURLConnection.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
            int cp; 
            while((cp = responseReader.read()) != -1)
            {
                response.append((char)(cp));
            }

            jsonResponse = response.toString();         
            Thread.sleep(DELAY); // Force a delay, apparently not enough...
        } 
        catch (relevantExceptions e)
        {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Parse the LatLng from the JSON response
        try 
        {
            JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);

            double lat = ((JSONArray) responseObject
                     .get("results"))
                     .getJSONObject(0)
                     .getJSONObject("geometry")
                     .getJSONObject("location")
                     .getDouble("lat");
            double lng = ((JSONArray) responseObject
                     .get("results"))
                     .getJSONObject(0)
                     .getJSONObject("geometry")
                     .getJSONObject("location")
                     .getDouble("lng");
            addressLatLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
            object.setLat(lat);
            objet.setLng(lng);

        } 
        catch (JSONException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (addressLatLng != null)
        {
            ....
        }
        else 
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to Geocode", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        // Write to the database 
        dbResult = dbHelper.commitRow(object);
        return addressLatLng;               
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        setProgressBarIndeterminate(true);
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(LatLng addressLatLng) 
    {           
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
    }
} // of getLatLong()
```

Relevant code in the Add activity that instantiates the AsyncTask:

```
    String addressToGeocode = address + 
                              " " + 
                              city + 
                              country;
    AsyncTask<String, Void, LatLng> geocodeTask = new Geocode();
    geocodeTask.execute(addressToGeocode);
```

The Add activity is invoked by a `ListView` activity like so:

```
    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    int itemId = item.getItemId();
    switch (itemId)
    {
        case (R.id.action_menu_add):
        {       
            Intent addIntent = new Intent(this, AddActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(addIntent, Contract.ADD_REQUEST_CODE);

            return true;
        }
        default: 
            return false;
    }
} // of onOptionsItemSelected()
```

The `ListView`'s `onActivityResult`

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        Bundle b = data.getBundleExtra(GlobeShopperContract.NEW_BUNDLE);
        MyObject d = (MyObject) b.get(Contract.NEW_BUNDLE_NAME);
            collection.add(d);              
        dViewAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);           
        dViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    else
        ...
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code? It is difficult to see what is going on from your story alone.

Comment: code is definitely required.

Comment: @BertPeters, the question is updated. Kindly investigate. Thanks again!

Comment: @BertPeters, thanks for seeing the question. Guess there's a different way to ask: 

Wondering if everything in an `AsyncTask`'s `doInBackground` method gets executed sequentially. In the code above, there's a JSON parsing block, AFTER which is a database write. How is the write happening BEFORE the parse completes? How can the write be forced to wait and execute ONLY AFTER the parsing completes? Thanks again!